# How to do session timeout in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

Here I want to make logout call before  30 doen.I want to store the logout time in DataBase.How to Maintain session in java.Here is my controller method will execute before logout.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout")
    public String showLoggedout(HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session){

        UserInformation userInformation = (UserInformation) session
                .getAttribute("userInfo");

        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        long t = date.getTime();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(t);
        java.sql.Time sqlTime = new java.sql.Time(t);
        java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(t);

        String userAgent = (request).getHeader("User-Agent");
        UserAudit userAudit = new UserAudit();
        userAudit.setUserid(userInformation.getUserId());
        userAudit.setLogoutdatetime(sqlTimestamp);
        userAudit.setLoginstatus("Logout");
        BrowserInfo browserInfo = new BrowserInfo();
        String browserInformation = browserInfo.getBrowserInfo(userAgent);
        userAudit.setDeviceInfo(browserInformation);

        appServiceManager.saveUserAudit(userAudit);

        session.invalidate();

        return "loginform";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

(*Edit as per comments*)

As per my understanding you want to perform some DB or other processing when the Session is timing out.

You can define a custom `HttpSessionListener` implementation that provides callback hooks on start/end as per below:

```
class MyCustomSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static final int SESSION_INACTIVE_TIME = 1*60;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(SESSION_INACTIVE_TIME);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        //do here your checks/cleanup at the end
    }
}
```

and register it in your `web.xml` as:

```
//..
<listener>
    <listener-class>my.path.to.MyCustomSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
//..
```

Comment: I alredy placed <session-config> in web.xml

Comment: are you using spring security?

Comment: Yes I am using spring security

Answer (score 0):

you can do in your web.xml (it will take 20 as min)

```
    <web-app ...>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
        </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

or in your java code for particular session (it will take input as Second)

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20*60);
```

> > to monitor session creation and other stuff you have to register
> >     sessionlistner in your web.xml

```
<web-app ...>
        <listener>
        <listener-class>com.example.sessiontracker </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class sessiontracker implements HttpSessionListener {

  private static int totalActiveSessions;

  public static int getTotalActiveSession(){
    return totalActiveSessions;
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    totalActiveSessions++;
    System.out.println("sessionCreated - add one session into counter");
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    totalActiveSessions--;
    System.out.println("sessionDestroyed - deduct one session from counter");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, u can ask what is confusing you

Comment: wiill the session calls sessionDestroyed before it invalidate

Comment: if you register this listener in your web configuration every time when session created your session created method will call and same for destroy

Comment: Yes It will definitely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129446/discussion-between-mike-and-koutuk).